# Including HTML UI in android

Tags: javascript, android, html

I want to include HTML UI for my android application (using android studio). I have taken one webview and included the HTML UI successfully, Now I am able to see the output also. But in the HTML UI there is one button for which I want to write onClick functionality. I tried but I am not getting output. Please help me out from here.
This is my HTML UI code.

ALL TAGS ARE CLOSED PROPERLY. I want to write onclick functionality right here

```
<a href="#english_page" class="lang-selector-options-eng" onClick = "onEnglsihClick('English Clicked')" data-transition="fade" data-value="eng">English</a></li>
<li><a href="javascript:;" onClick="onArabicClick('arabic is clicked')">Arabic</a>.
```

I have written on click function as I shown above , My Javascript code is here,

```
   <script type = "text/javascript">
        function onEnglsihClick(englishToast)
            {
                Android.showToast(englishToast);
            }
        function onArabicClick(arabicToast)
            {
                Android.showArabicToast(arabicToast);
            }
        </script>
```

When I click on English language Toast has to appear , in the same way for arabic language also. But When I click on English or Arabic I am not getting the output. My android code is here,

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@SuppressLint("JavascriptInterface")
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    WebView webView =  (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView);
    //enable JavaScript
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.addJavascriptInterface(new WebAppInterface(this) , "Android");
   // webView.loadUrl("http://vebdesignprojects.com/pro/geo-punch/160506/vehicle-detail-report.html");
    webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/html/map-screen.html");
}

public class WebAppInterface
{
    Context mContext;
    WebAppInterface(Context c)
    {
        mContext = c;
    }
    public void showToast(String toast)
    {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, toast, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    public void showArabicToast(String arabictoast)
    {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, arabictoast, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
}
```

All braces and and TAGS closed properly. Please help me.

Comment: Are you using Cordova or something ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't annotate your function for interface

```
public class WebAppInterface
{
    Context mContext;
    WebAppInterface(Context c){
        mContext = c;
    }

    @JavascriptInterface
    public void showToast(String toast){
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, toast, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @JavascriptInterface
    public void showArabicToast(String arabictoast){
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, arabictoast, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

For further informatio, see Android [Documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#addJavascriptInterface(java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.String))